# Computer not asking for password after waking from sleep

Tags: 14.04, password, suspend, lock-screen

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and set up an account with a password. I configured the computer to ask for a password after waking up from a sleep however, I am still brought back to desktop without a lockscreen.

Computer specs:
Lenovo IdeaPad Y580:

- Intel Core i7-3630QM (2.4GHz with Turbo up to 3.4)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M and Intel HD4000 (Optimus)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 14.04 LTS.

I found the setting here: <kbd>Settings Manager</kbd> -> <kbd>Power Manager</kbd> -> <kbd>Extended</kbd> -> check box for "Lock screen when going for suspend/hibernate".

Just in case this is still an issue for anyone.

Comment: Where is this settings manager or which package is it in?  I tried the Compiz Settings Manager but could not find that setting you mention.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: Same problem here. It is occurred today or from yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

have you done like following?
 1- go to System settings
 2- choose Brightness and lock
 3- Then:
    - set "Lock" option to "ON"
    - check the box in "Required my password when waking from suspend"
    - and set the time in "Lock screen after: "

Comment: 1. Yes I have.
2. You should put this in a comment rather than an answer.